# Confusion on using LognormalDistribution in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I would like to fit a `LogNormalDistribution[μ,σ]` based on some data that I have. Roughly speaking, would I need to take the `Log` of these data's *y*-values before calculating the mean and standard deviation in order to determine $\mu$ and $\sigma$ above, or can I calculate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ directly from the data and supply these values to Mathematica's `LogNormalDistribution`-function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Added in @gwr 's suggestion about using `SeedRandom` so the one can obtain exactly the same answers as below.

It's not clear that your question has anything to do with *Mathematica* but rather should you use maximum likelihood or method of moments (which would be best asked at CrossValidated).

Consider a random sample from a log normal distribution:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
n = 100;
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 0.3], n];
```

One can use the `FindDistributionParameters` function or brute force it:

```
(* Maximum likelihood *)
FindDistributionParameters[data, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]] 
{μ -> 0.940761, σ -> 0.291374}

(* Maximum likelihood the direct way *)
Mean[Log[data]]
(* 0.940761 *)
StandardDeviation[Log[data]] ((n - 1)/n)^0.5
(* 0.291374 *)
```

If you don't want to take the logs of the data, then consider the method of moments where you equate the sample moments to the population moments:

$$E(X)=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$$
$$V(X)=e^{2\mu} e^{\sigma^2}(e^{\sigma^2}-1)$$

```
(* Method of moments *)
FindDistributionParameters[data, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]
(* {μ -> 0.939427, σ -> 0.298547} *)

(* Method of moments the direct way *)
FindRoot[{Mean[data] == Exp[μ + σ^2/2], 
  Variance[data] (n - 1)/n == Exp[2 μ] Exp[σ^2] (Exp[σ^2] - 1)},
  {{μ, Mean[Log[data]]}, {σ, StandardDeviation[data]}}]
(* {μ -> 0.939427, σ -> 0.298547} *)
```

As to which method (or some other method) is best, that would be a question for CrossValidated.

Comment: Nice answer. I would suggest to use a defined `SeedRandom` when using `RandomVariate` so as to make your results replicable?

Comment: @gwr Good suggestion!  In fact, I thing I might open a question about that:  Does the same `SeedRandom` selection get the same sequence of random numbers among versions of *Mathematica* and among different operating systems.

Comment: I just tested `RandomVariate[ NormalDistribution[ ] , 1000 ]` given the same seed: Versions 10.4, 11.1.1, and 11.2 give the exact same values, which I confirmed by using `Hash`.

Answer (score 4):

There are slight variations in the distribution obtained depending on the specific approach taken

Generating data

```
SeedRandom[0]

data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[3, 1.5], 1000];
```

[`FindDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html) will conclude that this data has a [`LogNormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogNormalDistribution.html)

```
(dist1 = FindDistribution[data]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.875997585829534, 1.5560895409245938] *)
```

However, if you specify that it is a `LogNormalDistribution`

```
(dist2 = FindDistribution[data, 
    TargetFunctions -> {LogNormalDistribution}]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567956011853, 1.5056882462684804] *)
```

To force a fit to a `LogNormalDistribution` using [`FindDistributionParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)

```
(dist4 = LogNormalDistribution[m, s] /. 
    FindDistributionParameters[data, 
     LogNormalDistribution[m, s]]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567990925176, 1.505688384471444] *)
```

This is equivalent to

```
(dist5 = LogNormalDistribution[m, s] /. 
    FindDistributionParameters[Log[data], 
     NormalDistribution[m, s]]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567990925176, 1.505688384471444] *)

dist4 === dist5

(* True *)
```

Using the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) and [`StandardDeviation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html) of the [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) of the data

```
(dist6 = LogNormalDistribution @@ (#[Log[data]] & /@ {Mean, 
       StandardDeviation})) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567990925176, 1.5064417937677634] *)
```

Using [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) on the `Log` of the data

```
(dist7 = TransformedDistribution[E^x, 
    x \[Distributed] FindDistribution[Log[data]]]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567990925176, 1.5056883844714437] *)

(dist8 = TransformedDistribution[E^x, 
    x \[Distributed] 
     FindDistribution[Log[data], 
      TargetFunctions -> {NormalDistribution}]]) // InputForm

(* LogNormalDistribution[
 2.904567941143856, 1.505688383284438] *)
```